# Galera cluster is still accepting writes on a single node when 2 of 3 nodes are down

Tags: linux, mysql, cluster

I am running a 3 clusters galera database, and during redundancy tests, I saw that if I shutdown properly 2 of 3 nodes, the last one still accepts writes, even being the only only one up.

I am not sure that this is the way I want my cluster to work. Is it possible to set the cluster to reject writes when only 1 node is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster size (`wsrep_cluster_size`) is a dynamic value that scales up and down as you bring up and take down nodes in your Galera Cluster.

When you gracefully shut down two of your three nodes, you're effectively handing the [Primary Component](https://web.archive.org/web/20190611090340/http://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/glossary.html#term-primary-component) status to the remaining node.  **There is no risk of data diverging** (split-brain), so it is still safe for the last node to serve requests.  The cluster size becomes 1, and you're practically left running a single MySQL server.

> Is it possible to set the cluster to reject writes when only 1 node is up?

I don't think Galera Cluster works like this.  Conceptually, the nodes just care about forming a quorum.  For each of the nodes, if it is in the majority, it holds the Primary Component status.  The isolated nodes become non-primary.

If you abruptly lost two of your three nodes, then the remaining node will find itself in the minority, enter the non-primary status (shown in `wsrep_cluster_status`), and refuse reads and writes.

---

## Additional Resources

- [Weighted Quorum](https://web.archive.org/web/20190619065459/http://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/weighted-quorum.html) in the Galera Cluster Documentation
- How the Primary Component status stays with the majority:

  [image: How the Primary Component status stays with the majority]
- How Galera Cluster protects itself from split-brain scenarios by putting nodes without a majority into the non-primary status:

  [image: Example of split-brain]